# Download data from URL

Tags: r, download

It does not really align with stackoverflow policy since I am not showing what I have done but I really have no clue how to even start on this question given my lack of technical expertise. Hope someone can post a solution or at least point me to the right direction.

I want to download all the data from this website:

http://aps.dac.gov.in/APY/Public_Report1.aspx

I need to download all the data i.e. all season * all year * all states * all crops. The longer (frustrating!) way to approach is to just click all the boxes and press download.

However, I was wondering if anyone has any programming solution to download this data. I would preferably want to do this in R because that's the language I understand but feel free to tag other programming languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using RSelenium to instance a browser and direct it to do your bidding.

```
library(RSelenium)
driver <- rsDriver()
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("http://aps.dac.gov.in/APY/Public_Report1.aspx") #navigate to your page
```

You basically need to tell the browser to select each button you want to mark, using SelectorGadget to find the unique ID for each, then pass them one-by-one to webElem. Then use the webElem methods to make the page do things.

```
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id', value = "TreeViewSeasonn0CheckBox")
webElem$highlightElement() #quick flash as a check we're in the right box
webElem$clickElement() #performs the click
#now do the same for each other box

webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id', value = "TreeView1n0CheckBox") 
webElem$highlightElement()
webElem$clickElement()

webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id', value = "TreeView2n0CheckBox") 
webElem$highlightElement()
webElem$clickElement()

webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id', value = "TreeViewYearn0CheckBox")
webElem$highlightElement()
webElem$clickElement()
```

Now choose the report form you want and click the download button. Assuming it's Excel format here.

```
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id', value = "DdlFormat")
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list("Excel", key = "enter"))
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id', value = "Button1")
webElem$clickElement() #does the click
```

For what it's worth, the site timed out on trying to download all the data for me. Your results may vary.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try and get back to you if this works