# Using R to download data automatically

Tags: r, selenium, curl, web-scraping, download

I want to download all the data in either pdf or excel for 
each State X Crop Year X Standard Reports combination from [this website](https://aps.dac.gov.in/LUS/Public/Reports.aspx).

I followed this tutorial to do what I want. 
[Download data from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569481/download-data-from-url)

However, I hit an error on the second line.

```
driver <- rsDriver()

Error in subprocess::spawn_process(tfile, ...) : 
group termination: could not assign process to a job: Access is denied
```

Are there any alternative methods that I could use to download these data?

Comment: Are you using Docker? See http://ropensci.github.io/RSelenium/articles/docker.html

Comment: I am not using Docker and I am not familiar with it. Is it required to download these data?

Comment: do you have admin priviledges or are you at work?

Comment: I am at work so no admin privilege

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, check robots.txt on the website if there is any. Then read the terms and conditions if there is any. And it is always important to throttle the request below.

After checking all the terms and conditions, the code below should get you started:

```
library(httr)
library(xml2)

link <- "https://aps.dac.gov.in/LUS/Public/Reports.aspx"
r <- GET(link)
doc <- read_html(content(r, "text"))
#write_html(doc, "temp.html")

states <- sapply(xml_find_all(doc, ".//select[@name='DdlState']/option"), function(x)
    setNames(xml_attr(x, "value"), xml_text(x)))
states <- states[!grepl("^Select", names(states))]

years <- sapply(xml_find_all(doc, ".//select[@name='DdlYear']/option"), function(x)
    setNames(xml_attr(x, "value"), xml_text(x)))
years <- years[!grepl("^Select", names(years))]

rptfmt <- sapply(xml_find_all(doc, ".//select[@name='DdlFormat']/option"), function(x)
    setNames(xml_attr(x, "value"), xml_text(x)))

stdrpts <- unlist(lapply(xml_find_all(doc, ".//td/a"), function(x) {
    id <- xml_attr(x, "id")
    if (grepl("^TreeView1t", id)) return(setNames(id, xml_text(x)))
}))

get_vs <- function(doc) sapply(xml_find_all(doc, ".//input[@type='hidden']"), function(x)
    setNames(xml_attr(x, "value"), xml_attr(x, "name")))

fmt <- rptfmt[2] #Excel format
for (sn in names(states)) {
    for (yn in names(years)) {
        for (srn in seq_along(stdrpts)) {
            s <- states[sn]
            y <- years[yn]
            sr <- stdrpts[srn]

            r <- POST(link,
                body=as.list(c("__EVENTTARGET"="DdlState",
                    "__EVENTARGUMENT"="",
                    "__LASTFOCUS"="",
                    "TreeView1_ExpandState"="ennnn",
                    "TreeView1_SelectedNode"="",
                    "TreeView1_PopulateLog"="",
                    get_vs(doc),
                    DdlState=unname(s),
                    DdlYear=0,
                    DdlFormat=1)),
                encode="form")
            doc <- read_html(content(r, "text"))

            treeview <- c("__EVENTTARGET"="TreeView1",
                "__EVENTARGUMENT"=paste0("sStandard Reports\\", srn),
                "__LASTFOCUS"="",
                "TreeView1_ExpandState"="ennnn",
                "TreeView1_SelectedNode"=unname(stdrpts[srn]),
                "TreeView1_PopulateLog"="")
            vs <- get_vs(doc)
            ddl <- c(DdlState=unname(s), DdlYear=unname(y), DdlFormat=unname(fmt))
            r <- POST(link, body=as.list(c(treeview, vs, ddl)), encode="form")
            if (r$headers$`content-type`=="application/vnd.ms-excel")
                writeBin(content(r, "raw"), paste0(sn, "_", yn, "_", names(stdrpts)[srn], ".xls"))

            Sys.sleep(5)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my best attempt:

If you look in the network activities you will see a post request is sent:

[image]

**Request body data:**

If you scroll down you will see the form data that is used.

```
body <- structure(list(`__EVENTTARGET` = "TreeView1", `__EVENTARGUMENT` = "sStandard+Reports%5C4", 
                       `__LASTFOCUS` = "", TreeView1_ExpandState = "ennnn", TreeView1_SelectedNode = "TreeView1t4", 
                       TreeView1_PopulateLog = "", `__VIEWSTATE` = "", `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR` = "", 
                       `__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED` = "", `__EVENTVALIDATION` = "", DdlState = "35", 
                       DdlYear = "2001", DdlFormat = "1"), .Names = c("__EVENTTARGET", 
                                                                      "__EVENTARGUMENT", "__LASTFOCUS", "TreeView1_ExpandState", "TreeView1_SelectedNode", 
                                                                      "TreeView1_PopulateLog", "__VIEWSTATE", "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", 
                                                                      "__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED", "__EVENTVALIDATION", "DdlState", "DdlYear", 
                                                                      "DdlFormat"))
```

There are certain session related values:

```
attr_names <- c("__EVENTVALIDATION", "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", "__VIEWSTATE", "__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED")
```

You could add them like this:

```
setAttrNames <- function(attr_name){
  name <- doc %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = glue("//*[@id = '{attr_name}']")) %>% 
    html_attr(name = "value")
  body[[attr_name]] <<- name
}
```

Then you can add this session specific values:

```
library(rvest)
library(glue)
url <- "https://aps.dac.gov.in/LUS/Public/Reports.aspx"

doc <- url %>% GET %>% content("text") %>% read_html
sapply(attr_names, setAttrNames)
```

**Sending the request:**

Then you can send the request:

```
response <- POST(
  url = url, 
  encode = "form", 
  body = body,
  hdrs
)
response$status_code # still indicates that we have an error in the request.
```

**Follow up ideas:**

1. I checked for cookies. There is a session cookie, but it does not seem to be necessary for  the request.

   2. Adding headers.

Trying to set the request headers

```
header <- structure(c("aps.dac.gov.in", "keep-alive", "3437", "max-age=0", 
                      "https://aps.dac.gov.in", "1", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
                      "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36", 
                      "?1", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3", 
                      "same-origin", "navigate", "https://aps.dac.gov.in/LUS/Public/Reports.aspx", 
                      "gzip, deflate, br", "de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"), .Names = c("Host", 
                                                                                              "Connection", "Content-Length", "Cache-Control", "Origin", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", 
                                                                                              "Content-Type", "User-Agent", "Sec-Fetch-User", "Accept", "Sec-Fetch-Site", 
                                                                                              "Sec-Fetch-Mode", "Referer", "Accept-Encoding", "Accept-Language"
                      ))
hdrs <- header %>% add_headers
response <- POST(
  url = url, 
  encode = "form", 
  body = body,
  hdrs
)
```

But i get a timeout for this request.

**Note:** The site does not seem to have a robots.txt. But check the Terms and Conditions of the site.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

I tried running these 2 lines myself at work and got somewhat a more explicit error message than you.

```
Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
     Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
Check server log for further details.
```

[image: error]

It might be because if you are at work without admin privileges, R can't create a child process.

As a matter of fact I used to run into absolutely awful problems myself trying to build a bot using RSelenium. `rsDriver()` was not consistent at all and kept crashing. I had to include it in a loop with error catching in order to keep it running, but then I had to find out and delete gigabytes of temp files manually. 
I tried to install Docker and spent a lot of time doing the setup but finally it wasn't supported on my Windows non-professional edition.

Solution: [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) from Python is very well documented, never crashes, works like a charm. Coding in the interactive Spyder editor from [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) feels almost like R.

And of course you can use something like `system("python myscript.py")` from R in order to get the process started and the resulting files back into R if you wish so.

EDIT: No admin privileges are required at all for Anaconda or Selenium. I run it myself without any problem from work. If you have trouble with `pip install` commands being SSL-blocked like me you can bypass it using the `--trusted-host` argument.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. In my original question (which I have edited slightly) I am asking if there are alternate methods available to achieve what I need not necessary using Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is useful when you must run the javascript on a webpage. For websites that don't require the javascript to be run (i.e. if the information you're after is contained within the webpage HTML), [rvest](https://github.com/tidyverse/rvest) or [httr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/index.html) are your best bets.

In your case though, to download a file, simply use `download.file()`, which is a function in base R.

The website in your question is currently down (so I can't see it), but here's an example using a random file from another website

```
download.file("https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Paradis-rdebuts_en.pdf", "mygreatfile.pdf")
```

To check that it worked

```
dir()
# [1] "mygreatfile.pdf"
```

Depending on how the website is structured, you may be able to obtain a list of the file urls, then loop through them in R downloading one after another.

Lastly, an extra tip. Depending on the file type, and what you're doing with them, you may be able to read them directly into R (instead of saving them first). For example `read.csv()` works with a url to directly read the `csv` from the web. Other read functions may be able to do the same.

#### Update

I currently see an internal 500 error when I visit the site, but I can see the site via the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20190103003148/https://aps.dac.gov.in/LUS/Public/Reports.aspx), so I can see there is indeed javascript on the webpage. When the site is back up and running, I will attempt to download the files

Comment: @89_Simple 12 hours later and the site is still down. Do you know of anywhere else the data is stored?

Comment: I think the website is live again. Here's the direct link of it https://aps.dac.gov.in/LUS/Public/Reports.aspx